# Sharing documents with setmainfont breaks MikTeX's on the fly package installation

Tags: fonts, miktex, fontspec

When I share a document that uses fontspec's `\setmainfont` and the other person hasn't got the used font installed, they get an error. If the other person is using MiKTeX they are used to packages being installed on the fly.

What is the best way to tell MiKTeX which package to install for the set font?

Is it simply a usepackage of the desired font like this:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Tex Gyre Pagella}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: In generell it won't work. Fonts don't trigger the on-the-fly. There are not searched with miktex tools. After all they can be in the system folder outside miktex.  In the case of pagella \usepackage{tgpagella} should trigger the installation. Doesn't it work for you?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `tgpagella` is only the Type 1 version, no OTF included.  So even if this works `\setmainfont` will still complain.

Comment: @HenriMenke: In miktex tgpagella.sty is in the same package as the otf fonts, so if it gets installed with on-the-fly it installs also the other fonts.

Comment: Just tell your friend to install the `tex-gyre` package through the MikTeX package manager.  It can never be installed on-the-fly, because there is no such thing as `\usepackage{tex-gyre}`.

Comment: ``\usepackage{tgpagella}`` works. But I wanted to know the best way to solve this issue. Telling everyone whom I send the document to manually install a package is not a good way. Isn't there anything better than ``\usepackage`` like an option in fontspec?

Comment: No. As I already wrote: there is no general solution. Fonts must be installed manually. You can sometimes cheat if the miktex package with the fonts contains some file  that you can load with \usepackage. You can also sometimes trigger the on-the-fly if you use file names with extension in \setmainfont, but with font names it won't work. Beside: Someone who use a texsystem should be able to install a package.